# AutoCompleteTextView with SimpleCursorAdapter for Contacts not returning cursor actual value

Tags: android, android-contacts, autocompletetextview, simplecursoradapter

I have a AutoCompleteTextView that uses a SimpleCursorAdapter to filter emails for an input field. I have it working, although there are some `deprecated` commands that I am not sure how to rework.

The only problem I am having is that when I select a value from the list provided, I am not getting the email address selected, but something like the following:

```
android.content.ContentResolver$CursorWrapperInner@13a08d9c
```

Here is the code I have:

```
final AutoCompleteTextView edt_Contact = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(idTo);

    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    String[] projection={ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email._ID,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.ADDRESS};
    Cursor cursor = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null, null);

    startManagingCursor(cursor);
    String[] from = new String[] { ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.ADDRESS};
    int[] to = new int[] { android.R.id.text1};
    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, cursor, from, to);

    adapter.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider() {
        public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) {
            return getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI,
                    new String[] {},
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.ADDRESS + " LIKE '%" + constraint + "%'",
                    null, null);
        }
    });

    edt_Contact.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Any suggestions on how to get the actual selected value to populate the AutoCompleteTextView when selected?

Also, as mentioned, the deprecated items are `startManagingCursor` and `SimpleCursorAdapter`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution and I am posting it here for anyone else with a similar situation

I needed to add the following

```
adapter.setStringConversion(1);
```

I added it right before the last line in the example above.  This changed the result from the

*android.content.ContentResolver$CursorWrapperInner@13a08d9c*

to the selected email address.

Just a heads-up too for anyone using the `MultiAutoCompleteTextView` to do the same thing, this code works for that as well... just change add **Multi** before the `AutoCompleteTextView` and add the `.setTokenizer` of your choice.